# How build asp.net web site using nant script?

Tags: asp.net, nant

I am using **nant-0.90-alpha1**  to build asp.net 3.5 web site. I am unable do that. When I am using **msbuild** , it throwing error saying **unknown tag msbuild**. 
 How can I build asp.net 3.5 website using **nant**?

nRk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CodeCampServer](http://codecampserver.codeplex.com/) project provides good examples for a variety of tasks using nant to build MS projects including using MSBuild. However it doesn't use the msbuild task. Here's an excerpt from the common.build file from CodeCampServer:

```
<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <echo message="Build Directory is ${dir.build}" />
    <exec program="${framework::get-framework-directory(framework::get-target-framework())}\msbuild.exe"
              commandline="${file.solution} /t:Clean /p:Configuration=${project.config} /v:q" workingdir="." />
    <exec program="${framework::get-framework-directory(framework::get-target-framework())}\msbuild.exe"
              commandline="${file.solution} /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=${project.config} /v:q" workingdir="." />
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`<msbuild>`](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/msbuild.html) task is part of [NAntContrib](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks, Are there any examples or sample using NAntContrib with nAnt? Any samples or examples are very helpfule. Thanks

Comment: I found a question similar to Yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685571/build-vs2008-projects-with-net-2-0-net-3-5-using-nant

Answer (score 0):

The `<msbuild>` task must be imported into your build script. Put the following element somewhere within your `<project>` element.

```
<project ...>

    <loadtasks assembly="C:\Program Files\NAntContrib\NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.dll"/>

    ...
</project>
```

I believe NAnt will also pick up additional task libraries if the dlls are placed in the NAnt bin folder.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks, I downloaded ncover from sourceforge, but i didn't find as you specified.

Comment: @nrk: sorry for the confusion! I pasted the wrong path in there. See my updated answer.