# "Microsoft.CSharp.targets" file is missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

My C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.CSharp.targets file is missing from my computer. I closed my IDE, went on lunch, and then when I opened my IDE again, no C# projects would load.

I can see:

- C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets
- C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets
- C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.VisualC.STLCLR.dll

and several others, but no Microsoft.CSharp.targets.

What happened and how do I fix it?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694/the-imported-project-c-microsoft-csharp-targets-was-not-found) isn't helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was quite hesitant to try [this](http://chrisghardwick.blogspot.com/2008/10/microsoftcsharptargets-was-not-found.html) solution as the other machine running VS2008 was at a different patch/hotfix level, but it worked.

[Possible cause](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/4c05c392-b675-4300-b0fb-aeba1b97a990/)? An event log/system monitoring program that the company is running indicated that SQL Server 2000 was uninstalled from my machine two days ago, but I've never installed SQL Server 2000 on my machine to begin with!

Answer (score 0):

Reboot! Why? Not sure! It worked for me :)

Failing that "devenv.exe /ResetSettings" to run Studio as if it were the first time.

Please backup customized settings first.

Kindness,

Dan