# Does Hudson have a problem for building a CSPROJ file with MSBUILD?

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, hudson

Good morning

I'm running Hudson `java -jar hudson.war` and I have configured MSBuild as [described here](http://redsolo.blogspot.com/2008/04/guide-to-building-net-projects-using.html). It seems MSBuild is not working.

I think there is something to do with the default value contained in .csproj file:

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

This path is misleading, and takes Hudson to `C:\Microsoft.CSharp.targets` and not to `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.CSharp.targets` as it should be.

I tried to hard code the csproj file, with this full path information, but it throws an exception too telling there is an invalid character.

Maybe I'm using the wrong MSBuild.exe version?

Here is the Hudson message when using default `$(MSBuildToolsPath)` variable in csproj:

---

### Console Output

```
Started by user anonymous
Updating http://svn.mycoolserver.org/svn/repository/projects/trunk/MyCoolClassLibrary
U         MyCoolClassLibrary.csproj

At revision 36706
Path To MSBuild.exe: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe
Executing command: cmd.exe /C C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe /p:Configuration=Release MyCoolClassLibrary.csproj && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe /p:Configuration=Release MyCoolClassLibrary.csproj && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%

Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 2.0.50727.3053
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.3615]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2005. All rights reserved.

C:\Documents and Settings\myUser\.hudson\jobs\MyCoolClassLibrary\workspace\MyCoolClassLibrary.csproj(63,11): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, indeed I just needed to add the right path to

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also see the answer at the link below for another solution.

[The imported project "C:\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694/the-imported-project-c-microsoft-csharp-targets-was-not-found)