# Csproj file in unity changes everytime i reload the project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, msbuildcommunitytasks

I want to change the 'csproj' file of my unity project in order to be able to access a specific library as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694/the-imported-project-c-microsoft-csharp-targets-was-not-found) answer sugests.

I am manually editing the file but every time i reload the project, the 'csproj' file returns to it's initial state.

Is this a common issue? Is there a way to avoid this and change the file permanently?

---

EDIT: My goal is to use **CSharpCodeProvider** so if there is another way of doing it without changing the 'csproj' file, i will gladly adopt the approach

Comment: Unity tends to rewrite those files whenever it detects a code change, which can be very annoying in circumstances like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot prevent Unity from overwriting your csproj files upon recompilation of your scripts.

When working with larger code bases and Unity3D I tend to put most of my code into separate .Net assemblies (DLLs). This helps me when I'm sharing code between multiple projects and game servers, and Unity doesn't need to compile all scripts when it detects changes.

To do that fire up your .Net IDE of choice and create a new *class library* project (which will output a .dll). Make sure it is targeting the **.Net Framework 3.5** or lower. Then, you copy the output .dll into you Unity project's *Assets* folder in a post-build step. I like to use a post-build step to prevent me from forgetting to copy the assembly after a change.

DLLs in the project's *Assets* folder are automatically referenced by Unity when it creates its C# projects. This means all of the containing code can be used from within your scripts. Note, though, that the other way around will not work as easily: you cannot use code from Unity scripts in your separate project.

Depending on what exactly you want to do with [CSharpCodeProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) you can put your generation logic (and the necessary `Import` directive) into such a separate project.

Edit: For more information how we set up our project structure you can watch [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndt1crp9i7M) by the lead programmer on Jagged Alliance Online from Unite11.

Comment: That talk was good. A similar strategy was used by _Blackbird Interactive_ in _[Unite 2013 - Nurturing Large Projects: How We Structured Hardware: Shipbreakers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q9aeNtKKXeo)_.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is an easy-to-implement and fully working solution. I am going to post as an answer here the code i've used to create the dll file, in case someone else wants to use the CSharpCodeProvider object in his Unitiy project.

Comment: Starting with Unity 2018, you can target .NET Standard 2.1 instead of .NET Framework 3.5.

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness:

There is an undocumented feature in Unity which allows you to edit the generated `.csproj` files (programmatically), by using an `AssetPostprocessor`:

Inside any folder under `Assets` named `Editor`, create a class with the following structure:

```
public class CsprojPostprocessor : AssetPostprocessor {
        public static string OnGeneratedCSProject(string path, string content) {
            return PatchCsprojContent(content);
        }
    }
```

where `PathCsprojContent` is a function which returns a patched version of the `.csproj` file with the additions you need.

In case you want to patch only certain `.csproj` files, you can check the path beforehand. For example, if you want to process only the Asset `.csproj` file called `Assembly-CSharp.csproj`, you can add the following check to the start of `OnGeneratedCsProject`:

```
if (!path.EndsWith("Assembly-CSharp.csproj")) {
    return content;
}
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/extensibility/customize-project-files-created-by-vstu

Answer (score 0):

As Suigi suggested, i have created a .dll file with the help of a .Net IDE ([SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/)) and just copied it in the 'Assets' folder of unity.

([How do i create a .dll file with SharpDevelop](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/p/14349/38210.aspx))

Here is the class that i wrote to produce the .dll file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Reflection;

namespace dllTest {

public class AssemblyGeneration {

    public static Assembly generateAssemblyFromCode(string code, string assemblyFilename) {
        CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
        parameters.OutputAssembly = assemblyFilename + ".dll";
        CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);

        Assembly assembly = null;
        if (!results.Errors.HasErrors) {
            assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
            return assembly;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

In order to use it in any unity script, just use the namespace 'dllTest'. Then, you can call AssemblyGeneration.generateAssemblyFromCode(...) .

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need to compile code at runtime?

Comment: I am trying to create a learing platform for programmers in the form of a game, where the player needs to actually write code in order play. So, the code to compile is written at runtime by the player.

Comment: Interesting idea. Beware, that some platforms (iOS, Win RT) prohibit you from just-in-time compiling code. If you want to target those platforms, you might want to think about doing it via integrating a scripting language (e.g. Lua). This also has the benefit of you being able to control what the player can actually do, instead of allowing them to basically inject any arbitrary code.

Comment: Thanks, i will defenetly check it out since it may eliminate some issues i could have with my approach.