# The imported project "C:\Dot42.CSharp.targets" was not found

Tags: sharpdevelop

I installed Shardevelop yesterday and I can't open any Android templates without getting this error message.

> The imported project “C:\Dot42.CSharp.targets” was not found

The error message also tells me that there is a .csproj file in my project folder. However, I can't seem to find it.

Comment: sounds like it cannot find dot net??

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694/the-imported-project-c-microsoft-csharp-targets-was-not-found) help?

Comment: I edited my post Thomas, there is no csproj file in my project folder.

Comment: I've found a way to bypass the error, but every time I want to compile the app it gives me the error: "Compiling single files is not supported."

Answer (score 1):

I got around this issue by copying all the dot42.*.target files to the root of my c:\ drive from C:\Program Files\dot42\Android