# Error MSB4019 when importing project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to build a code which we have in our system. While building I am getting following error. Can someone please help?

> **[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(321,5): Error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.**

```
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8048376Z Project "C:\agent\_work\2\s\Hma.Portal.WinFormProject.sln" (1) is building "C:\agent\_work\2\s\Hma.Portal.WinFormProject\Hma.Portal.WinFormProject.csproj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8057282Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(321,5): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. [C:\agent\_work\2\s\Hma.Portal.WinFormProject\Hma.Portal.WinFormProject.csproj]
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8060584Z Done Building Project "C:\agent\_work\2\s\Hma.Portal.WinFormProject\Hma.Portal.WinFormProject.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8120334Z ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(321,5): Error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8121658Z Project "C:\agent\_work\2\s\Hma.Portal.WinFormProject.sln" (1) is building "C:\agent\_work\2\s\Hma.EntityModels.MasterDatabase\Hma.EntityModels.MasterDatabase.csproj" (4) on node 1 (default targets).
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8122756Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(321,5): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. [C:\agent\_work\2\s\Hma.EntityModels.MasterDatabase\Hma.EntityModels.MasterDatabase.csproj]
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8124717Z Done Building Project "C:\agent\_work\2\s\Hma.EntityModels.MasterDatabase\Hma.EntityModels.MasterDatabase.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8156228Z Done Building Project "C:\agent\_work\2\s\Hma.Portal.WinFormProject.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8194186Z 
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8194643Z Build FAILED.
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8284957Z 
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8301560Z "C:\agent\_work\2\s\Hma.Portal.WinFormProject.sln" (default target) (1) ->
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8302094Z "C:\agent\_work\2\s\Hma.Portal.WinFormProject.Setup\Hma.Portal.WinFormProject.Setup.vdproj.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8302402Z (Build target) -> 
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8302821Z   C:\agent\_work\2\s\Hma.Portal.WinFormProject.Setup\Hma.Portal.WinFormProject.Setup.vdproj.metaproj : warning MSB4078: The project file "Hma.Portal.WinFormProject.Setup\Hma.Portal.WinFormProject.Setup.vdproj" is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built.
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8303239Z 
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8311556Z 
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8312013Z "C:\agent\_work\2\s\Hma.Portal.WinFormProject.sln" (default target) (1) ->
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8312372Z "C:\agent\_work\2\s\Hma.Portal.WinFormProject\Hma.Portal.WinFormProject.csproj" (default target) (3) ->
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8314303Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(321,5): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. [C:\agent\_work\2\s\Hma.Portal.WinFormProject\Hma.Portal.WinFormProject.csproj]
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8315306Z 
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8315460Z 
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8315785Z "C:\agent\_work\2\s\Hma.Portal.WinFormProject.sln" (default target) (1) ->
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8316173Z "C:\agent\_work\2\s\Hma.EntityModels.MasterDatabase\Hma.EntityModels.MasterDatabase.csproj" (default target) (4) ->
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8316836Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(321,5): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. [C:\agent\_work\2\s\Hma.EntityModels.MasterDatabase\Hma.EntityModels.MasterDatabase.csproj]
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8317318Z 
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8318040Z     1 Warning(s)
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8318493Z     2 Error(s)
2018-10-16T19:50:53.8323589Z
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please review the Help pages on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure you provide all of the information needed to help answer your question.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5694/1531971 (among so many others). Show your research.