# Problem of Running Monodevelop-Stable on Linux

Tags: linux, cross-platform, monodevelop, archlinux, manjaro

I've tried to install Monodevelop-Stable on Arch-Based Linux ( Manjaro ) and i'd fault 3 times, it wasn`t possible to build from Github sources or from AUR or Flatpak, so i decided to use [monodevelop-stable-bin](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/monodevelop-stable-bin/) also from AUR, but when i tried to run my app , i got this problem

> "$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk (MSB4019)

Another words:

> "MonoDevelop/7.0/MSBuild/2472_1/Microsoft.Csharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk (MSB4019)

But i have in my directory:

> Microsoft.Csharp.Crosstargetting.targets

Notice , that this answer also wasn`t helpful:
[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694/the-imported-project-c-microsoft-csharp-targets-was-not-found)

Question is indeed so popular on the internet , but i still haven`t found an answer , and i need some help

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I talked a bit more in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61848732/12036073), but the short of it is that, for now, it seems that there is no way to use `Monodevelop` on `Arch` based systems.

I recommend using a `Ubuntu` based distro for programming (there are many other similar problems with `Arch`). There `Monodevelop` should work just fine.

Of course, you can try to use other IDEs, like [JetBrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) (I haven't personally tested it) or just use text editors with appropriate extensions, like [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or [Atom](https://atom.io/).