# Problems trying to use Monodevelop on Manjaro

Tags: c#, ide, monodevelop, archlinux, manjaro

I can't get `monodevelop` to work on `Manjaro`. I tried all the different options to install in `AUR` (`monodevelop-beta`, `monodevelop-bin`, `monodevelop-git`, `monodevelop-nuget3`, `monodevelop-stable`) and most of them failed to build.

The only one that didn't fail was `monodevlop-bin`, but I couldn't get it to build my program. At first I got this error:

```
The imported project "/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found.
Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. (MSB4019)
```

There was no folder "Roslyn" in the specified location. I made a folder with that name and copied the file `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` from `msbuild/15.0/bin/` in the "Roslyn" folder (renamed the copy to `Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets`).

It probably wasn't a good idea, but I tried it, just in case.

That did seemed to work, but then I got another error:

```
Parameter "AssemblyFiles" has invalid value "/usr/lib/mono/4.7-api/mscordlib.dll".
Could not load file or assebly 'System.Reflection.Metadata, Version=1.4.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a or' or one of its dependencies. (MSB3248)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> doctorzeus commented on 2019-12-14 14:34
>
> Since the issues with compatibility with the latest version of mono and msbuild as well as 
>   there no longer being a "stable" build mode on the github project I am disowning this project.
>
> Sadly I stopped using this IDE in favor of VSCode a while ago and also no longer have the time to maintain it with the large number of incompatibilities with the various dependencies.
>
> Hopefully someone with more time will take over..

This is from the original maintainter/builder (at the time of writing) in the [comments of the AUR page](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/monodevelop-stable/). After him, it seems that another person tried to continue maintaining it, but he still failed:

> coder2000 commented on 2020-03-31 18:51
>
> The build process is currently broken and the documentation is incomplete.

So, for now, you can't use `monodevelop` on `Arch` based systems (at least from `AUR`). You will have to use alternative IDEs, like [JetBrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/), or text editors (with proper extensions), like [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or [Atom](https://atom.io/).

Also, from personal experience, I would advice against using `Arch` based distributions for programming, because of problems like that. Use `Ubuntu` or something `Ubuntu` based for easiest experience with programming tools (I use `Linux Mint` for programming and I haven't had any major problems).